# transfer data dynamically with netty

Tags: java, network-programming, netty

I've been learning Netty for a while, and from the Netty's tutorials(the MEAP book), almostly the examples are based on a fixed framework, like the `EventLoop`, `Bootstrap`, it seems that only the implementations of the handlers in the `channelPipeline` are the things we really should be concerned about.

Here I wanna design a simple chess game, based on a Server/Client mode, where two players are on different computers. And the background data I want to use Netty to transmit.(I just wanna practice using netty)

And in such a game, the front GUI detect the player put a chessman and then make some change to the data. Then, I need to deliver this data to the other player. And here comes the question.

I don't know how to implement a `ChannelHandler` in this situation, because in most examples, it seems that the data are not added **dynamically** by the handler. For instance, the data was created when channel was active by the method `channelActive()` or something else. All these methods was auto-invoked by Netty itself.

The only method I think is the `write()`. However, it seems that I have to call this method by myself if I implements this method, I don't know where I can get the parameter `ChannelHandlerContext`.

So, how to solve problems like this?

---

p.s. 
I'm not so familiar with java network programming, nor the Netty. All the things I learn is based on the book, which I haven't finished reading yet. :)

Answer (score 1):

Channel hander of Netty looks

```
package netty_sample;

import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.MessageEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler;

/**
 * Server side action
 */
public class EchoServerHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {
    /**
     * This method will be invoked when server recieved a message
    */
    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent event) {
        String msg = (String) event.getMessage(); // extract a message received

        // You can write any code which handles the message, changes data, and create message for client, etc. 

        ctx.getChannel().write(someMessageToClient); // send back to client
    }
}
```

As I understand, handler routine is invoked dynamically (in event-driven) when server received a message.
So code in the handler works dynamically, and you can write anything in the code.